# Pizzapi module for Python not running outside IDLE

Tags: python, attributeerror

So I'm bored and trying to redo old projects. I had worked with the "pizzapi" module for Node.js back around '18 and wanted to try the python version. I did a few tests in IDLE with good results but when I made a new file to run all the code from, the module isn't adding any of the functions. At first I thought it was an issue with scope but I boiled it down to it's most basic part and realized it's just not adding any of the classes. I changed it to this

```py
from pizzapi import *

customer = Customer("First", "Last", "email@email.com", "18008675309")
```

and got

```py
NameError: name 'Customer' is not defined
```

So I changed to

```py
import pizzapi

customer = pizzapi.Customer("First", "Last", "email@email.com", "18008675309")
```

and get the error

```py
AttributeError: module 'pizzapi' has no attribute 'Customer'
```

If anyone can help with this, I am using Python Version 3.6.4 and Pizzapi 0.0.6, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Make sure your script name is not "pizzapi.py".

Comment: @Tiger-222 You are a good person. Thank you.